# plotting two dependent variables against independent variable on 2-D plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to plot two dependent variables, electron temperature and electron density against height, like the one shown in the image. [image]

```
Temperature = [1215.91011364417 1850.01332752710    396.195674732049    2.33318763425785    367.128785760659    1.12519845278610    1041.54280237670    308.561781429331    1403.27246459229    914.721893718804    1131.60868755734    1.12519845278610    614.410587642758    1.46315184861483    1639.85277962398    1.12519845278610    1298.88722417057    1031.22681754873    1436.00999906341    1668.58036010507]
Density = [24649439880.5505 30331375517.0950    32468687222.5687    24308807814.9539    21341517237.4872    35308667370.9386    40665492231.7457    45722093820.9962    51868188863.5582    47190795319.6345    42040060503.1364    32476984617.6228    40532684718.7974    30900215185.8408    34036581740.8683    26599891957.8216    30350230720.2869    33729881290.5469    38973963811.7042    52412248580.7820]

Height = [137.189200000000  137.125590000000    137.194550000000    137.350140000000    137.236270000000    137.254610000000    137.181080000000    137.180590000000    137.233510000000    137.257010000000    137.651370000000    137.182300000000    137.196620000000    137.224820000000    137.189600000000    137.249430000000    137.219690000000    137.130160000000    137.194210000000    137.246930000000].
```

All the three variables are `1x20`.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `Height` must be of the same dimensions as `Density` or `Temperature` if you want to plot these last two variables against the first one. With the data as shown in your question, you can't because `Height` is `4x1` and the other two variables are `1x20`. You want `Height` to be `1x20` as well.

Comment: Sir, you mean that height should be 1x20 as well?

Comment: For every density and temperature sample you need a height sample. The dimension of all vectors should be same. This is what @am304 means.

Comment: Thanks to both of you @am304 and @ Hazem for your time. But, the problem is that my height is only a column vector (264x1) and i want to plot the temperature and electron density only against the four heights shown in the question and this four heights mean four rows (4x1). Could you help me to reshape the height so that the requirement for the plotting is fulfilled. Thanks

Comment: @ABDURRAUF: you can't. Variables **have** to be the same size to be plotted against each other, what you're asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: @am304 thanks, but from your first comment, i understand that my height should be similar to that of temperature and electron density. Now as you could see my height is also 1x20.

Comment: @Sardar Usama, I want to plot electron temperature and electron density against height, similar to that shown in the attach image.

Comment: @Sardar Usama, Thank you very much.

Comment: If I just plot Temperature against Height, it gets really messy, is that correct? It is nothing like the picture above. I think the problem is that the values for height and temperature do not correspond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shows the figure with the data you provided. I create two sets of axis, each hold one data. The second set of axis has the x-axis on top, and is transparent.

```
Temperature = [1215.91011364417 1850.01332752710    396.195674732049    2.33318763425785    367.128785760659    1.12519845278610    1041.54280237670    308.561781429331    1403.27246459229    914.721893718804    1131.60868755734    1.12519845278610    614.410587642758    1.46315184861483    1639.85277962398    1.12519845278610    1298.88722417057    1031.22681754873    1436.00999906341    1668.58036010507];
Density = [24649439880.5505 30331375517.0950    32468687222.5687    24308807814.9539    21341517237.4872    35308667370.9386    40665492231.7457    45722093820.9962    51868188863.5582    47190795319.6345    42040060503.1364    32476984617.6228    40532684718.7974    30900215185.8408    34036581740.8683    26599891957.8216    30350230720.2869    33729881290.5469    38973963811.7042    52412248580.7820];
Height = [137.18920  137.12559    137.19455    137.35014    137.23627    137.25461    137.18108    137.18059    137.23351    137.25701    137.65137    137.18230    137.19662    137.22482    137.18960    137.24943    137.21969    137.13016    137.19421    137.24693];

% Reorder data
dat = cat(2,Height', cat(2,Density', Temperature'));
dat = sortrows(dat);

ax = {}; % holds both axes handle

figure
hold all

% first axis, first plot
ax{1} = gca;
plot(dat(:,3),dat(:,1),'ko-')
ax{1}.Box = 'off';
ax{1}.XLabel.String = 'Temperature';
ax{1}.YLabel.String = 'Height';
% second axis, second plot
ax{2} = axes();
plot(dat(:,2),dat(:,1),'k-.')
ax{2}.Color = 'none';
ax{2}.YTick = [];
ax{2}.XAxisLocation = 'top';
ax{2}.XLabel.String = 'Density';
ax{2}.XScale = 'log';

% Overlap both axis
ax{1}.Position = ax{2}.Position;

% Clean it up a little bit
ax{1}.XLim = [ 0 3000];
ax{2}.XLim = [1e10 5.3e10]; % You might want to change units here?
```